# Multiple outcome for a bidirectional constraint using implication operator

Tags: system-verilog

Is there a way we can write multiple outcome for a bidirectional constraint?

```
constraint c_test{
     (packet_size == LARGE) -> (Packet_length == 16); (Gap_betwn_packets == 2);
}
```

The Above code shall have Packet_length as 16 and Gap between packets as 2 whenever the packet_size is LARGE .Is the above code okay?

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be written as a group of constraints using `{}`

```
constraint c_test{
     (packet_size == LARGE) -> { Packet_length == 16; Gap_betwn_packets == 2; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Dave! I tried it and it show an illegal concatenation syntax [4.1.14(IEEE)].

Comment: By referencing concatenation operator in section 11.4.12 of the 1800-2017 LRM, I changed the above solution to constraint c_test{
     (packet_size == LARGE) -> { Packet_length == 16   ,  Gap_betwn_packets == 2 };
}

Comment: Can you please let me know if that is the right approach?

Comment: Sorry, I had the `;` transposed. Corrected